# How to get the Key and the Value of Dictionary<int, string> returned from method

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm collecting data dynamically and I've chosen `Dictionary<int, string>` as data structure to store this data.

At the beginning of my method I declare a variable :

```
Dictionary<int, string> templatesKeyName = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

at the end of the method I want `templatesKeyName` to contains all pairs of int (ids) and Names relevent for this request. So for example I have:

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> GetTemplateForUserWithAccount()
{
Dictionary<int, string> kv = new Dictionary<int, string>();
//populate the `kv` dictionary
return kv;
}
```

and I want to be able to do something like:

```
if(Client.Accounts.Count > 0)
{
  templatesKeyName.Add(GetTemplateForUserWithAccount());
}
```

Obviously `.Add()` extension expects two arguments but I wasn't able to find out how can I pass the values from the method without writing first assigning the result to e temporary Dictionary and then iterating with `foreach`.Also, most likely I will get single result most of the time so iteration is not something that I consider really.

Comment: Iteration has to happen either in your code or in a method you call. What is wrong with `foreach (var item in GetTemplateForUserWithAccount()) templatesKeyName.Add(item.Key, item.Value)`?

Comment: @adrianm Not that something is wrong but as you can see from  `Selman22` answer - there's still a way to keep the logic at one place so I don't have to write the iteration logic each time I call similar method. Also, other collections implement `AddRange` by default, so I thought that there should be better way to add those values.

Comment: I was mere thinking about the maintainer of your code. Now there will suddenly be an `.AddRange` added to all dictionaries. A maintainer might start using it in other places expecting it to work as `.AddRangeReplaceExisting` when it really does `.AddRangeIfNotExists`. Good method naming and documentation will solve it of course but is it worth the trouble.

Comment: @adrianm Good point. Gonna choose appropriate name. Thnaks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension method for that:

```
public static void AddRange<T,K>(this Dictionary<T,K> source, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,K>> values)
{
    foreach(var kvp in values)
    {
       if(!source.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
          source.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

And use it like the following:

```
templatesKeyName.AddRange(GetTemplateForUserWithAccount());
```

Comment: Interesting. I was expcting to find this method implemented, why they haven't implemented `AddRange` for `Dictionary`.... However works perfect for me. Thanks

Comment: @Leron - With a `List` (where `AddRange` is already implemented) you can have duplicate entries. But a `Dictionary` must not have the same key twice. So what should the default behaviour be? Overwrite the value for the existing key? Skip if key is present? Throw an exception? This implementation choses to "Skip if key is present". But somewhere else it might be better to overwrite. And still somewhere else throwing an exception would be appropriate. The developers probably didn't want to decide on *one* specific standard implementation. And as you see, it's easy to make your own.